# First row of pandas dataframe became the row index. How to make it back to the row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like this. The first row of the df became the row label (or index). How to make it a row in the df.

| Index | apple | 10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | orange | 20 |
| 1 | pine | 30 |

I need to format it like this,

| Index | Fruit | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | apple | 10 |
| 1 | orange | 20 |
| 2 | pine | 30 |

Comment: Hey @Kabilash, try to use concise, reproducible code examples that show your problem. Better yet, provide your own attempt, so fellow users can help you fix the code in _your_ context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step by step explanation:

1. need to assign the header to first row of the dataframe
2. sort the index after adding
3. reset index will remove the -1 index
4. add the columns names to the dataframe
5. assign the proper index number to the index column. so it will remove the index for apple

Use this code:

consider your dataframe name as `df`

```
df.loc[-1] = df.columns.values
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.columns = ['Index','Fruit','Count']
df['Index'] = df.index
```

Output:

```
    Index   Fruit   Count
0   0       apple   10
1   1       orange  20
2   2       pine    30
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are reading this data from a csv, in this case when you do that, you can define header line:

```
df.read_csv('/path/to/file', header=None, columns=['Index', 'Count', 'Count'])
```

or just

```
df.read_csv('/path/to/file', columns=['Index', 'Count', 'Count'])
```

If you add more info I'll revise my answer.